# How to configure/use CheckStyle in Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2

I want to learn how to use CheckStyle.

I am doing static code analysis in Hudson, as first part, I installed Static Analyser and CheckStyle plugins in Hudson. But I am not able to find out how to use it in official Hudson checkstyple page also.

official page : http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Checkstyle+Plugin

I saw some documents in Maven checkstyle plugin that we have to mention some configuration in pom file and run the targets.

Then, I got doubt, if I am doing with Maven, why we need the CheckStyle plugin install in hudson?

Is it possible to configure CheckStyle in Hudson job for a Java project instead of changing in pom or not? It here is both ways, then which one is better?

Do you have the steps to configure CheckStyle plugin in Hudson?

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the plugin in Jenkins/Hudson, you should now be able to add the checkstyle goal to your project/job.

In the goals section of your Jenkins Maven job, add "checkstyle:checkstyle" to enable the checkstyle plugin to analyse your project.

Comment: Hi, I am not using Maven, but Ant script to compile my Java project. How do I configure checkstyle in Ant? Again, as Dmitry mentioned in his question, that way I won't be using the Checkstyle plugin, right?